# URL-Redirecting on host_name in browser in tomcat9 using classes/project/servlet

Tags: servlets, web-applications, web.xml, tomcat9, web-inf

I would like to redirect to particular servlet `doGet()` when `hostname.com` hits in browser.

I have been going around in this basic issue. Please guide.

I have a folder structure of my legacy application in windows environment:

```
D:\tomcat9\webapps\root\web-inf\classes\ProjectName\SRC\SomeFolder.
```

This **SomeFolder** has a list of servlets.

**What I Did:**

1. tried to replaced index.jsp in ROOT folder with response.SendRedirect("/servlet-url-mapping-path");
2. tried to add extra hosts in server.xml which destroyed my application loading even.

Help  (Yes this is very old legacy application, not even using jsps.)

Comment: Cut ProjectName folder from classes and paste in webapps folder.Do not alter any thing in ROOT folder.